# USQL Query for Huge Files

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a very large file in the Azure Data Lake store (257 gb), and when I tried to do a simple extract on it yesterday I got the following error

> *Vertex terminated as it ran for more than 5h hours. The input size of the vertex SV1_Extract_Partition[0][53].v0 with guid
>   {2F8802B8-F93A-47EE-80E2-274590BD76A5} is 1.171594 GB. In most
>   situations, this is caused by data skew such as one data partition
>   containing most of the data. Use of different partitioning scheme or
>   re-partitioning data can resolve such issue.*

So I'm pretty sure what is happening is that U-SQL is not properly partitioning my file. I'm using a custom written extractor, but I don't see why this should be and issue.

How do I ensure that I partition my files. This mistake has cost me a lot of money (More than $2000), so I really don't want to run anything in this scale again before I can ensure that my files are properly partitioned when the job is running.

Do I really have to manually split my file into smaller files?

Comment: Can I suggest working on a sample file of say 2.57GB (or even MB), making your process nice and efficient so it finishes in say, less than one minute, then scaling up to 20GB to ensure your process scales linearly and so on ...

Answer (score 2):

The partition size of about 1GB seems normal. The problem is probably in your custom extractor that it does process that data for over 5 hours.

I would suggest to investigate what your extractor does on that particular partition of the file.

Comment: Hey Michael, First of thanks a lot for the quick answer. I really appreciate the support you and Saveen are providing the community. So the partition size, is what I expected. I downloaded the input files for the failed vertex (5 in total). The first file seems to be starting mid line, where there shouldn't be a line break (or anything resembling one, since the previous character was a "b"). Furthermore I see that each line becomes 1114 columns instead of the original 557. I will investigate some more, but if you have any insights which might help me, please let me know.

Comment: If your data is partitioned into rows, then you should be using the input.Split() command (see for example https://github.com/Azure/usql/blob/master/Examples/FlexibleSchemaExtractor/FlexibleSchemaExtractor/Script.usql.cs) instead of directly operating on the basestream. This has to do with that the files are split into chunks regardless of end of lines. The input.Split call will peek 4MB into the next chunk to find the end of line and skip the data from the previous line at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will look into this :)